# Which games do I really need to mount in a Garrys Mod server?

Tags: server-administration, source-engine, garrys-mod, hosting

Up until this point I've had TF2 and Counter Strike:Source mounted on every server regardless of the gamemode. I want to cut down on HDD usage.

Which games do I actually need to mount for different gamemodes? Some people have half life episodic mounted too which I don't think is important for my gamemodes.

My gamemodes are:

- TTT
- Prop Hunt
- Murder
- Deathrun

They all have very little custom content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CS:S has everything you need, but TF2 is in the instructions because it has nice maps and I think some of them use the same textures. I would mount TF2 too.

Answer (score 0):

CS:S is pretty much all you need. There are a couple of maps you might run into that require EP2 content, but almost everything is either CS:S or custom textures.

Comment: So any idea why the instructions have TF2 in them? Is it just an example?

Answer (score -3):

All you need to mount is Team Fortress 2, Counter Strike: Source, and Half Life Episodes 2.